# Is this a valid proof of set membership

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $S=\{x \in\mathbb{Z}: x\geq0, x=b-a ×m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Prove that if $b\geq0$ then $b$ is an element of $S$.

Pf: suppose $b\geq 0$
Let $a$ be an integer
     define $b=b-a×m$
Where $m=0$.

So $b=b-a×0=b$

Thus $b$ is an element of $S$.

Is this a correct proof? I feel torn whether it is or not because aren't I more or less assuming one of the requisite conditions to be a member of $S$ when I define $b=b-a×m$?

However, I feel like the alternative is awkward... i.e.

Let $b = b$
It is apparent that $b=b=b-a×0$
Where $a$ is any integer.
Thus there exists an '$m$' ($0$ namely) such that , $b = b - a×m$.
So $b$ is an element of $S$.

Comment: Did you claim $a_0 = 0$ on purpose?

Comment: Nope looks like someone went and reformatted it for me, should be a multiplication between a and m and a subscript m

Comment: Note that $\;b \ge 0 \;\Rightarrow\; b \in S\;$ does not hold for $\;b \not\in \mathbb Z\;$, so the statement as currently given is not true.

Comment: By the way, here is how I would write down this proof:$$
\newcommand{\MXs}[1]{\\=\quad&\quad\unicode{x201c}\mbox{#1}\unicode{x201d}\\\quad&}
\newcommand{\MXz}{\in\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\MXr}[2]{#1\ge 0\;\land\;\langle\exists m:m\MXz:#2\rangle}
\begin{align}\quad&
b\in\{x\MXz\mid\MXr x{x=b-a\times m}\}
\MXs{basic property of set builder}
b\MXz\;\land\;\MXr b{b=b-a\times m}
\MXs{arithmetic:simplify}
b\MXz\;\land\;\MXr b{a\times m=0}
\MXs{RHS is true, witness $\;m:=0\;$}
b\MXz\;\land\;b\ge 0
\end{align}$$ See also [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's not. You claimed $a_0 = 0$ when you wrote $b - a_0 = 0$.

Your original claim is false for general sequences $\{a_m\}$. We have $b \in S$ if and only if $b = b - a_m$ for some $m$, which is true if and only if $a_m = 0$ for some $m$.

Comment: Sry the post should say (a)(m) that is, a time m, and not a subscript m